# Plain object exchange between UWP and Win32 apps using DesktopBridge

Tags: c#, winapi, uwp, desktop-bridge

Can we pass plain objects between UWP and Win32 (WinForm or WPF) application using DesktopBridge? 
I have tried with **Protocol Extension** and **AppServices**, but the only option is we can exchange data in form of String content only.
Eventhough I tried with NewtonsoftJson to serialized object to string and deserialized object in UWP as dynamic object. But its working partially and getting issue with complex objects.
But need to pass whole object (both properties and methods) from Win32 application to UWP.

Comment: What you are asking for is known as RPC, remote procedure call. Not sure it's available readily in this context and I very much doubt it's the right solution.

Comment: "But its working partially and getting issue with complex objects"  , Describe the issues in detail please and to see if it can be resolved since using App Service should be a correct way.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT Refer this Github project [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServiceBridgeSample). There the data is exchanged in form of string content only. Consider if I have User object with some property, unable to pass the object as **POCO** object.
And if the passing object is **dynamic** Newtonsoft deserialization is not working as expected.